# Google-Apps-Script - Development version is the Published Version

Tags: google-apps-script

I just noticed this and have no idea how to fix this...

Until recently, I have been able to test (the /dev version) separately from the live ( /exec version).  But now, any change I make is instantly "Live".  All I do is "Save" , not Publish.

Nothing is shared, no one has edit privileges other than myself.

Any thoughts.  Like I said, it has all been fine in the past, but something changed recently, but I have no clue - have checked all permissions that I can find - nothing shared.

Comment: I've voted to close your question.  If you want to know whether other people are having the same problem, it's better to post to the Apps Script group.  [Link To Apps Script Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)  If you could create a video to prove what is happening, that would be the best.  If it really is a bug, you'll need to prove that it's valid and not just a mistake made by you.

Comment: I would like to know how it could be a mistake made by me...  I have the /exec site that has been working absolutely fine for over a year now, and just happened to notice that a simple change, like adding an input when "Saved" - not "Published" appeared on the /exec site.  I even verified by going to another users computer that has no access other than "View" (i.e. they can access the site) and there was the input box.  But I will post on "Apps Script Community", but I thought this sort of issue was possibly a google-apps-script issue - sorry new to this and don't know all of your "rules".

Comment: It can be frustrating and difficult to get answers, and it often happens that the user gets unfairly blamed.  The rules on Stack Overflow get broken constantly, and there is constant misunderstanding.

Comment: I wanted to provide some additional information that may help on this issue - if this is not the appropriate place then please let me know...  here goes.

Comment: here is some code that I am using

Comment: Sorry forget this.. not sure how to format this so it is clear - rediculous.

Comment: Was trying to show the code - can't figure out this mini-Markdown formatting thing...  it is interesting however that I just tried this deleting most of the code and when I initially launch the EXEC version it is correct, I can go to a page and return using the ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() and when I return to the index page where I made the cahnge it suddenly appears...   I think this is a bug, but have no idea how to report...  Thanks to anyone that would care.

Comment: You can report this on the Issue Tracker:  [Link to Issue Track](https://issuetracker.google.com)  The people who fix bugs need to be able to reproduce the problem, which is often a lot more difficult than you might think.  They do care, and will try to help.

Comment: they already knew about it.